# Cannot Access News API id in Swift

Tags: json, swift, api

I get this error when I try to run my code because I cannot figure out how to access the id of the json file.

When I run my code, I get this error:

```
    keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Here is my code that retrieves the data from the API

```
   func fetchData() {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&category=science&apiKey=7806d7a294994cd2af9d272bbfe4f334") {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let safeData = data {
                    do {
                        let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                        // Update must happen on the main thread, not in the background
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                             self.posts = results.articles
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is the postData code:

```
    struct Results: Decodable {
        let articles: [Post]
    }

    struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
        var id: String
        let title: String
        let url: String
    }
```

Finally, here is my code that is supposed to render the data on the screen:

```
    struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        // for every single post in the post array
        List(networkManager.posts) { post in
            Text(post.title)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Science Bite")
    }
        // This calls fetch data
        .onAppear {
            self.networkManager.fetchData()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are missing the step `source` where you'll find the `id`. That's what is saying the error. If you pretty format your JSON, you'll see that `id` isn't on the same level as `title` and `url`. Either you add yourself another struct, OR you use a custom init for that nest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Larme has said you're trying to decode `id` from `article` but it's actually present in the dictionary of `source`. Modify your `Article` model to the following to fix the issue:

```
struct Article: Codable {
    let title, url: String
    let source: Source

    var id: String? {
        source.id
    }
}

struct Source: Codable {
    let id: String?
}
```